# No "clean" targets found

Tags: gruntjs

Please help, I use Grunt and try to do *grunt clean* command, but I have

> No "clean" targets found.

message as a result. How can I fix that?

```
    copy: {
        build: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                src: [
        "fonts/**/*.{woff, woff2}",
        "img/**",
        "js/**",
        "*.html"
      ],
                dest: "build"
    }]
        }
    },

    сlean: {
        build: ["build"]
    }
});

grunt.registerTask("serve", ["browserSync", "watch"]);
grunt.registerTask('default', ['copy']);
grunt.registerTask("build", [
"clean",
"copy",
"sass",
"postcss",
"csso",
"imagemin"
]);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the character `c` in `clean` - in the grunt configuration literal - is not what it appears to be. It's `U+0441` - a Cyrillic letter.

If you retype it and ensure that it is an ANSI `c` - or copy and paste the word `clean` from the `registerTask` call - your `grunt` configuration should behave as you are expecting it to.